# Is reinterpret cast from vector of pointers to vector of const pointers safe?

Tags: c++, vector, constants, reinterpret-cast

Is this conversion type safe

```
vector<int*> a;
const vector<const int*>& b = reinterpret_cast<const vector<const int*>&>(a);
```

A static cast obviously doesnt work in this case because the template argument is changing. But by doing this reinterpret cast, I am just adding constness to essentially the same type. So should this be safe for all practical purposes?

Comment: One way that it could realistically go wrong (although I haven't confirmed this by a test) is strict aliasing. The optimizer is entitled to assume that `b` does not refer to the same memory as `a` (because it has a type which is not compatible for aliasing). Then the optimizer will play its tricks, and you might find that it re-orders or elides things that it would not re-order or elide if `a` and `b` *validly* referred to the same memory. So, identical layout is a necessary but not a sufficient condition for it to "work".

Comment: Another way to look at it, is that the result of a `reinterpret_cast` to a reference or pointer type is *fundamentally* useless and doesn't work for anything other than converting back to the original type, unless either (a) the destination type is legal for aliasing the actual type of the object, or (b) you have some particular assurance from your implementation that it supports the specific thing you're doing. When neither one applies, don't refer to an object via any type other than its own. Doing so is also called "type-punning".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like any use of `reinterpret_cast` to convert a reference to an unrelated type, it gives undefined behaviour, and so is not safe unless you define "safe" to mean "works on my compiler".

Comment: Wouldn't it be ok to assume that vector of any pointer has the same structure after all they are just addresses. Or can the structure actually change because of the type of the pointer.

Comment: @user1353535: No, the library implementation is free to specialise the template however it likes. There's no requirement for different specialisations to be layout-compatible.

Comment: So if its a user defined type which the library cant possibly specialize, then?

Comment: @user1353535: There could still be a partial specialisation for `const` types. You could perhaps argue that reinterpreting a vector of one standard-layout user-defined type as a vector of a layout-compatible user-defined type is unlikely to give any ill effects, but the behaviour would still be undefined.

Comment: An alternative definition of "safe" is, "works on all compilers in existence at time of writing". It's stronger than your definition, it might be the case for this code, but of course it's still UB.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, you could use that definition, if you're prepared to test it on all of them.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: for a practical example of the use of that definition -- it is "safe" to assume in C++03 that string storage is contiguous. That wasn't established by me testing them all, though, it was established by an informal poll at a C++0x committee meeting.